# How to returns custom std::Fmt::Error type when implementing Display and using serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I'd like something like this:

```
impl Display for IntervalType {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.write_str(&serde_json::to_string(self).map_err(|e| std::fmt::Error::Custom(e)?)
    }
}
```

so that I can use my rules set in serde attributes like rename etc. I don't want to unwrap the serde error but I cannot find a way to convert into fmt::Error type. What do?

Comment: From [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Error.html): "This type does not support transmission of an error other than that an error occurred. Any extra information must be arranged to be transmitted through some other means." If you don't want to preserve the serde error (which you really shouldn't need to), then just map with a constant: `.map_err(|_| std::fmt::Error)`

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why the Error was an empty struct. I totally forgot I could just instantiate it like that